# spacing rightBarButtonItems in UINavigationBar

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationitem

i am using the `rightBarButtonItems` property of UINavigationBar to add two buttons on the right part of my navigation bar. is it possible to make the spacing between these two buttons wider?

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add an `UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace` item between your two buttons.

```
UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                                                      target:nil
                                                                      action:nil];
```

Comment: i'm assuming i should use `UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace` :D

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to get the flexible space to work in my situation but here is the code I used to be able to position the rightBarButtonItem:  Note, I put a border around the UIView so you can see what it looks like with having the image in there.

```
UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(89,40,100,30)];
containerView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
containerView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nav-icon.png"];
UIButton *navigationButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[navigationButton setFrame:CGRectMake(67,0,25,25)];
[navigationButton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[containerView addSubview:navigationButton];

UIBarButtonItem *navigationBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:containerView];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = navigationBarButtonItem;
```